# How to view triggered goals

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, goals

The instance name is `mysite.org` and I have used the Facebook share button. The site is not a public URL yet. The goal points to the related goal is set to 10.

Here are the issues:

1. In preview mode, the facebook button is visible, clicking on which the login dialog appears. But when I publish the page, this button is not rendered.
2. In preview mode, when I click on share and log in with facebook credentials, the Likes number increased to 1 from 0. But nothing came up on my facebook page. Is it because mysite.org is not a public URL?
3. I want to check the goals/points achieved, but in Content Editor - Analyze > reports, the value is 0. Should this not be 10 or more (as I have been trying more than once.)

How Can I check the triggered goals (in Mongo or SQL) . Using Sitecore 8.2

[image]

Comment: On point #3, is your Analytics enabled? if it is enabled then in sitecore 8.0 you can use Sitecore experience analytics option present on Dashboard. it shows various reports. from here you can check statistics of goals triggered.

Comment: In Sitecore.xdb.config, the enabled property is set to true. The dashboard or the Analyze panel (as in pic) show no data.

Comment: I have observed, at times the report at the Content / Item level was showing 0, the reason because the existing report is getting reloaded again and again, better close and re-open the report for each content / item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see it 2 different ways :

1. If it is pagebased goal then goto that item in sitecore and then click analyze panel and then click on reports and select page - goals and events
2. By going to the analytics dashboard --> Conversions --> goals (below screenshot) and then browse the individual goal by click on that goal (blue bar in graph) (so under exp analytics it should read something like Dashboard --> Goals --> Goal)

[image]

Comment: My pic already shows what you have suggested in 1. In dashboard it says, no data to display. How can I confirm if that goal is page based?

Comment: @Qwerty, i think your screenshot is of the goal itself and i am asking you to goto the actual sitecore item and not to the goal item. So lets say you have about us item in sitecore content tree under home node and if you have set up a goal on that item then you need to goto that item and follow the steps as per your notes. but if you want to see the goal and how much value it have collected then you need to goto my step 2 instructions under the exp analytics, does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you Mrunal. You were right. I was looking at the goal itself. When I checked the reports for the particular item, it did show some data. But why is it so. If viewing a page/sharing triggers a certain goal, should not the Goal's reports also show some data. Because, the goal's data is still 0.

Comment: @Qwerty so to me sitecore implemented it right. since your goals are associated to content and if someone visits the page/content you collect values by triggering goal so that means you are collecting values for your content and not for your goals. If you want to see the goal and its value generation then you need to goto the analytics section and find it there. You can also right custom report to show you how much value this goal have generated for you and can personalize based of that.
This is what i think but i could be wrong too.