# How many times has my goal been triggered

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, goals

This is somewhat related to [How to view triggered goals](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/3689/148)

We are working on a solution where we need to trigger an analytics goal when someone submits a form. I've got that working by triggering the goal programatically and can see the goal registered as a conversion.

What I'm wondering is why I'm only seeing one visit. This is from a QA environment where multiple people have triggered the goal (submitted the form) several times. I was expecting to see how many times the goal has been triggered in total and also how many different users / sessions have triggered the goal. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to increase the range of the date filter?

Comment: How are you triggering the goal? Code or in Sitecore?

Comment: @ChrisAuer I'm triggering the goal through code

Comment: @HishaamNamooya the date filter is correct. I've just gone back in to re-check the results and it is now showing 3 visits and a total count of 4 ( so I assume it has registered that the goal was triggered four times). My guess is that there is some background process that had to run to update this report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to consider.

Firstly, your data will be initially written to session of that user. Once that session expires only it will be get written to xDB.

You can reduce the session expire time on your test environment to speed-up the data written process to xDB by adjusting the values mention on the below question
[How do I set session timeouts in Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2145/how-do-i-set-session-timeouts-in-sitecore)

Secondly, there is a threshold to update the analytics reports set on several places.
One place would be to set "MinimumVisitsFilter" to "0" on \Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Reports\Dashboard\Configuration.config

Also following blog post describes few other options though it is written to sitecore 6 versions.
https://learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/tag/refresh-aggregated-data-in-reports/